# Supporting HTTPS URL redirection with a single CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a domain `formulagrid.com`.

I am using AWS S3 to host it as a static website. My problem was that I wanted to redirect the www subdomain to the bare domain like so:

- `https://www.formulagrid.com -> https://formulagrid.com`
- `http://www.formulagrid.com  -> https://formulagrid.com`

Amazon provides URL redirecting from S3 bucket to S3 bucket if both are setup for static website hosting.

So what I had to do was set up two buckets:

- `formulagrid.com` - actual website
- `www.formulagrid.com` - exists solely to redirect to the actual website

This works perfectly fine if you're operating only over HTTP, but S3 has absolutely no support for HTTPS.

The way that one can use HTTPS to connect to an S3 static website is by setting up a CloudFront distribution in front of an S3 bucket. CloudFront, however, while it does provide HTTPS, mainly exists to function as a CDN.

Initially, I had a single CloudFront distribution setup in front of the S3 bucket holding the actual site. Everything seemed operational:  the site was distributed over the CDN, it had HTTPS, and HTTP redirected to HTTPS.

There was one exception.

- `https://www.formulagrid.com` was a completely broken page

After trying to find the source of the error for a while, I realized it's because it wasn't going through the CDN, and trying to access S3 over HTTPS doesn't work.

Finally, what I ended up having to do was provision another distribution to sit in front of the `www` S3 bucket so it was accessible over HTTPS. This is where my concerns come in because, like I mentioned earlier, CloudFront's main purpose is to be a CDN.

It doesn't make any sense to me to have a CDN sit in front of a url that just redirects to another. Also it brings up the question of whether I would be double charged for every request that hits the `www` subdomain because it'd hit the other CloudFront distribution after being redirected.

This is frustrating because I'm trying to do a "serverless" architecture using Lambda, and having to provision an EC2 instance just to do url rewriting isn't something I want to do unless it's my last resort.

The solution would be trivial if Amazon offered any form of URL rewriting or if CloudFront itself did redirecting, but neither of these exist as far as I know (let me know if they do).

I'm new to AWS so I'm hoping someone with more experience can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're thinking too narrowly -- there's nothing wrong with this setup.

> The solution would be trivial if Amazon offered any form of URL rewriting

They do -- the empty bucket.

> S3 has absolutely no support for HTTPS.

Not for web site hosted buckets, no... but CloudFront does.

CloudFront is not just a CDN.  It's also an SSL offloader, `Host:` header rewriter, path prepender, geolocator, georestrictor, secure content gateway, http to https redirector, error page customizer, root page substituter, web application firewall, origin header injector, dynamic content gzipper, path-based multi-origin http request router, viewer platform identifier, DDoS mitigator, zone apex alias target... so don't get too hung up on "CDN" or on the fact that you're stacking one service in front of another -- CloudFront was designed, in large part, to complement S3.  They each specialize in certain facets of storage and delivery.

So, you did it right... most of it, anyway... Create a bucket, configure it for web site hosting, set it to redirect all requests to another site (the non-www) and put a CloudFront distribution in front of it -- using the web site endpoint URL for with bucket in CloudFront, not the one from the drop-down list -- configured with high TTLs so that CloudFront will send a minimal number of requests to S3 then put your (free!) SSL certificate from Amazon Certificate Manager.  HTTPS alternate domain routing: solved.  No servers, no troubleshooting, and cheap.  The *only* charges are the usage -- there is no background recurring charge as there would be with servers.

Extra credit: configure the redirecting CloudFront distribution for the cheapest rate tier.  Redirects from more expensive locations will either be routed to a cheaper edge location or -- at CloudFront's option -- may be served out of a higher cost location but billed at the lower rate.

Note that most of the time, CloudFront should serve the redirects from S3 from it's cache... and when you configure a bucket to redirect all requests to another hostname, the redirect is a `301` *permanent* redirect -- which browsers are supposed to cache, themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I basically have done everything you said. There's one question I have though. For requests that get redirected, wouldn't it go `CDN -> empty S3 -> CDN -> S3`? That's my main problem.

Comment: After CloudFront caches the redirect from the empty bucket it would be CF > CF > S3, and if the S3 site content is cached, just CF > CF.  After the initial landing they're redirected to the bare domain and subsequent links would keep them there... this should not perform any differently than if CF had the native capability to redirect to different domain -- those initial requests would still hit CF twice, since the redirect takes the browser to what the browser will *always* assume is a different place, because the hostname changes... whether it's actually the same machine or not.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean I'd be charged twice per redirected request? Once for each CF request?

Comment: Yes, an extra $0.000001for each HTTPS request.  ($1 per million).

Comment: Haha so not a real concern. Even if it were more expensive it'd still probably be cheaper than an EC2 server to do the redirecting. Thank you.

Comment: ...but you have to pay *somebody* to do the redirect.  If the same distribution handled it, it would still require a second request.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot great answer, I am trying to do exactly the opposite of OP. i.e. apex to WWW redirect. would that mean my Website bundle would reside in my www.website.com S3 bucket and website.com would be the empty one? I am slightly confused here :(

Comment: @Annjawn yes, you can redirect any hostname to any other using a second distribution and a second bucket.