# Redirect traffic with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have deployed a static site with AWS S3, CloudFront, and Route53.
The site works fine with the apex url (example.com).

Now I wish to add also www.example.com so, I have created an empty bucket and redirected all the traffic to the first bucket.

What should I do on CloudFront?  Create a distribution for the empty bucket?

Thanks

Comment: You redirected the www bucket to the example.com bucket?  Or to example.com (which, in DNS, is presumably now pointing to CloudFront, not directly to the bucket)?  It isn't clear what problem you're trying to solve at this point.

Comment: To the example.com bucket as described her http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html at Step 2.2. In the walkthrough, Route53 refers directly to the bucket. I want to have CloudFront in between. What should I do?

Comment: You want CloudFront in between the browser and the bucket for the www redirect?  [Like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35616286/1695906)

Comment: Forget about what I have done. What is the correct way (also for a SEO standpoint) to use S3, CloudFront, and Route53 to host a static website available at example.com and www.example.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a new CloudFront distribution. The trick here is to NOT use the proposed bucket values, but use the endpoint directly.

In example, this is my bucket endpoint:

```
 redirect-jekyll.io.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

An this would be the proposed endpoint which you SHOULD NOT use:

```
 redirect-jekyll.io.s3.amazonaws.com
```

The difference is, only the endpoint would send you the redirect. You can receive your endpoint address by going to the S3 console and look at the properties. Setting that, will make your CloudFront distribution using a "Custom target", which is perfectly find for your use case.