# HTTPS for multiple services AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https

I have a website that depends on multiple auxiliary services, to which it makes http requests. (These services e.g. provide information from data probes to update the website via ajax in real-time, and are written in a different language to the website so that I can't use RMI or similar.)

I'm trying to secure the website with SSL so that it displays as secure in browsers, but due to the http requests to the auxiliary services I'm getting mixed content warnings. I'm hosting on AWS which only seems to allow https requests to the single port 443, on which I have my website itself listening; how can I set things up so that I can access my auxiliary services securely if I need them to listen on a different port to the website?

EDIT: I should add that this is for our test website, so there's no load balancing enabled...

Comment: You get mixed content because some of these services are not having SSL it seems. If so you can put them behind a proxy with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very easily solved with CloudFront.

Forget all about caching and the fact that CloudFront is a CDN.  It isn't *just* those things. [It has a number of other useful tricks up its sleeve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35616286/1695906).

CloudFront is also a reverse proxy that can route requests to multiple destinations ("origin servers"), including multiple ports on a single instance, based on the request path (cache behaviors)... meanwhile, the browser thinks everything is coming from a single web site and is speaking HTTPS to CloudFront, yet CloudFront can optionally speak ordinary HTTP to the back-end services if that is a security policy you allow.  A single CloudFront distribution can have up to 25 path mappings (including the default catchall mapping for the main site), referencing up to 25 different backend IP/Hostname+port combinations.