# Redirect www subdomain to an apex (naked) domain on Route 53 (not using S3)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

How do you redirect a www subdomain to an apex (naked) domain using Route53 and CloudFront?

Please note I am not using S3. 
My site is hosted behind an ELB on the AWS ECS service.

I've tried to create a Record Set with the following settings:

```
- Name: www 
- Type: CNAME - Canonical name
- Alias: No
- TTL (Seconds): 300
- Value: example.com
```

In CloudFront I have only the `example.com` apex whitelisted. As a result, the request is blocked.

I've also tried adding the `www.example.com` entry in CloudFront and the site resolves, however, the browser is not redirected `example.com`

Comment: How about using mod_rewrite (if you are using apache)?

Comment: Thanks @TitiWangsabinDamhore much appreciate the comment. Trying to do it in Route53 if possible however the fallback is Nginx.

Comment: as far as I know, route 53 alone, cannot do this. The job of route 53 Is to translate domain name to IP. HTTP 1.1 allows that one IP to have multiple domain. The client requests www.abc.com and the only way to request abc.com is if there is a 30x response. This is not handled by r53.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are considering to redirect using CloudFront and Route53, currently  you have to write an [Edge Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html) for [HTTP Response Generation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-response-generation.html) to Redirect.

Comment: Many thanks, @Ashan. Looks like HTTP Response Generation is exactly what I'm looking for. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-response-generation.html

Comment: Lambda@Edge is still in preview.  The current solution involves a second CloudFront distribution and an empty bucket. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35616286/1695906

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot for the link. The current solution is definitely a hacked approach that I'd like to avoid. I'll go with the preview and make adjustments if needed.

Answer (score 4):

AWS have introduced [CloudFront functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html) which can manipulate the requests and responses that flow through CloudFront.

To redirect a www subdomain to the apex domain you can use the following viewer request function:

```js
function handler(event) {
  var request = event.request;

  var headers = request.headers;
  var host = request.headers.host.value;

  if (host.startsWith('www')) {
    var response = {
      statusCode: 301,
      statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
      headers: {
        location: {
          value: 'https://' + host.replace('www.', ''),
        },
      },
    };

    return response;
  }

  return request;
}
```

In order for this function to work the CloudFront distribution needs to be configured with both the www subdomain and the apex domain. You will also need to configure Route 53 with both the subdomain and apex domain.

Using S3 for the redirect is not possible for domains (such as [.dev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dev)) where the entire gTLD has been included in the HSTS preload-list because S3 website do not support https.