# How to redirect non-www traffic to www for site hosted on EC2 instance behind CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I host a site on a single EC2 instance behind CloudFront and need to redirect all non-www traffic to www.

From other Q/A here on SO I was able to configure an A record on Route53 to redirect traffic from example.com to www.example.com. However, this only works for http traffic, not https traffic.

How can I get the **https** traffic for the naked (non-www) URL to redirect to my canonical URL https://www.example.com?

*I know there are similar questions asked already, but I don't see any with my same configuration (most are for sites hosted in an S3 bucket or for redirecting from www to non-www).*

#### Current URL handling situation

```
https://www.example.com - Canonical URL for the site, handled by CloudFront
http://www.example.com - CloudFront redirects to https://www.example.com
https://example.com - Unreachable!!!
http://example.com - Route53 redirects to https://www.example.com via S3 bucket
```

#### Other details

The CloudFront distribution uses an AWS-generated certificate which covers the following domains:

```
*.example.com
example.com
```

Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) listed in the distribution are:

```
www.example.com
example.com
```

Route53 has the following A records:

```
www.example.com -> CloudFront distribution
example.com -> S3 bucket, configured to redirect to www.example.com
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like I described in [this answer to a slightly different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35616286/1695906), the solution is to create a second CloudFront distribution in front of an empty bucket for the variant of your domain name that you want to redirect.

Configure the bucket to redirect, and when you configure the second CloudFront distribution to point to that redirecting bucket, be sure you type in the web site hosting endpoint for the bucket -- don't select the bucket from the Origin Domain Name drop-down list.

Remove `example.com` from the Alternate Domain Name setting on the existing distribution, and configure it on the new one.

You can use the same ACM cert on both distributions.

Point `example.com` to the new CloudFront distribution in DNS.

Comment: For the second (the redirect) CloudFront distribution, should the default Viewer Protocol Policy "HTTP and HTTPS" be used?

Comment: Is the CNAME for the redirect distribution supposed to be example.com and the CNAME for the website distribution supposed to be www.example.com?

Comment: For the redirection, Viewer Protocol Policy HTTP and HTTPS will potentially reduce the number of redirects by 1, since Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS will add an unnecessary extra redirect prior to the one you want, and HTTPS Only will not work for this application.  Yes, the Alternate Domain Name ("CNAME") settings should be as you described.

Comment: But S3 can't handle HTTPS traffic right? So if I redirect HTTP and HTTPS traffic from CloudFront to the S3 redirect bucket then how does the HTTPS traffic get to my website distribution from S3?

Comment: You asked about *Viewer* protocol policy.  That's only between the viewer and CloudFront, not between CloudFront and S3 (or whatever origin server).  CloudFront will send the back-side request to S3 over HTTP while speaking either HTTP or HTTPS with the browser, and (for lack of a better word) translating between the two.

Comment: in route53 there is a CNAME record added which is pointing to a CloudFront distribution where the alternate domain is example.com. Now if I create second distribution to put in front of the empty bucket it won't let me put example.com again as an alternate domain. What to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: There is no good way.  (Personally, I don't consider hacky workarounds a solution.)

The long answer is:

There is no good way, but there is a way.  I guess.

I've seen S3 and EC2 recommended by AWS staff in their forums. S3 is a non-option as you've noted.  EC2 is probably the most "correct" until route53 or cloudfront can handle this.

1. Create an ec2 web server and install ssl suitable for example.com (letsencrypt)
2. Configure it to redirect example.com -> www.example.com
3. Add an A record that points to the ec2 server
4. (This won't work because EC2 doesn't support public IPv6) Add an AAAA record that points to the ec2 server

You can probably get away with skipping IPv6 support, but if you need it, ELBs support it -- so have fun with that.

Answer (score 0):

You need **one more cloudfront distribution** so there are **2 cloudfront distributions** in total.
Then, you don't need **any s3 buckets**. Just use **2 cloudfront distributions**. Finally, you configure **route 53**.

**This is the instruction below ↓↓↓**

**Step 1**: Create the first cloudfront distribution.

Configuration:

```
Origin Domain Name : "www.example.com"

Viewer Protocol Policy : "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS"

Cache Policy : "Managed-CachingDisabled" (Default is "Managed-CachingOptimized")

Alternate Domain Names(CNAMEs) : "example.com"

then, select "Custom SSL Certificate".
```

**Step 2**: Create the second cloudfront distribution.

Configuration:

```
Origin Domain Name : "33.72.129.67" (Input your ec2 instance public ip like this)

Viewer Protocol Policy : "Redirect HTTP to HTTPS"

Alternate Domain Names(CNAMEs) : "www.example.com"

then, select "Custom SSL Certificate".
```

**Step 3**: Assign the first(step 1's) cloudfront distribution to "example.com" on route 53.

**Step 4**: Assign the second(step 2's) cloudfront distribution to "www.example.com" on route 53.

That's it!!

Supplementally saying, you cannot connect cloudfront to the ec2 instance in private subnet. The ec2 instance in public subnet is ok to connect to cloudfront.