# Cloudfront does not redirect properly to https and subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48198816) post and [this](https://simpleit.rocks/web/hostings/redirect-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www-with-aws-s3-bucket-cloudfront-route-53-and-a-custom-domain/) article, one should create a second cloudfront distribution in front of an S3 bucket which redirects to another bucket, which contains the static files.

Asuuming the frontend bucket name is `www.example.com` and the redirect bucket is `example.com`. I have set up my AWS resources according to the following cloudformation template.

However, some problems occur: If I hit example.com it does not redirect to www.example.com, only when I have clicked another link on the site. In addition, it does not load the favicon for example. http://example.com is redirect to https://example.com. http://www.example.com it does not redirect to https, the webiste is not found.

What am I missing in my AWS settings?

[This](https://simpleit.rocks/web/hostings/redirect-http-to-https-and-www-to-non-www-with-aws-s3-bucket-cloudfront-route-53-and-a-custom-domain/) mentions to not set the Default Root Object property, which I did not. But maybe it is related somehow?

```
FrontendBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.frontendBucketName}
        AccessControl: PublicRead
        WebsiteConfiguration:
          IndexDocument: index.html
          ErrorDocument: 404.html
    RedirectdBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.redirectBucketName}
        AccessControl: PublicRead
        WebsiteConfiguration:
          RedirectAllRequestsTo:
            HostName: ${self:custom.frontendBucketName}
            Protocol: https

WebAppCloudFrontDistribution:
  Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
  Properties:
    DistributionConfig:
      Origins:
      - DomainName: ${self:custom.frontendBucketName}.s3-website.${self:provider.region}.amazonaws.com
        Id: Frontend
        CustomOriginConfig:
          HTTPPort: 80
          HTTPSPort: 443
          OriginProtocolPolicy: http-only
      Enabled: 'true'
      Aliases:
      - ${self:custom.frontendBucketName}
      CustomErrorResponses:
      - ErrorCode: 404
        ResponseCode: 200
        ResponsePagePath: /index.html
      DefaultCacheBehavior:
        DefaultTTL: 31536000
        MaxTTL: 31536000
        MinTTL: 31536000
        AllowedMethods:
        - DELETE
        - GET
        - HEAD
        - OPTIONS
        - PATCH
        - POST
        - PUT
        TargetOriginId: Frontend
        ForwardedValues:
          QueryString: 'false'
          Cookies:
            Forward: none
        ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        AcmCertificateArn: 'arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxx:certificate/xxxx'
        SslSupportMethod: 'sni-only'

RedirectCloudFrontDistribution:
  Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
  Properties:
    DistributionConfig:
      Origins:
        - DomainName: ${self:custom.redirectBucketName}.s3-website.${self:provider.region}.amazonaws.com
          Id: Redirect
          CustomOriginConfig:
            HTTPPort: 80
            HTTPSPort: 443
            OriginProtocolPolicy: http-only
      Enabled: 'true'
      Aliases:
      - {self:custom.redirectBucketName}
      DefaultCacheBehavior:
        DefaultTTL: 31536000
        MaxTTL: 31536000
        MinTTL: 31536000
        AllowedMethods:
        - DELETE
        - GET
        - HEAD
        - OPTIONS
        - PATCH
        - POST
        - PUT
        TargetOriginId: Redirect
        ForwardedValues:
          QueryString: 'false'
          Cookies:
            Forward: none
        ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
      ViewerCertificate:
        AcmCertificateArn: 'arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxx:certificate/xxxx'
        SslSupportMethod: 'sni-only'


DnsRecord:
  Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSet"
  Properties:
    AliasTarget:
      DNSName:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - WebAppCloudFrontDistribution
          - DomainName
      HostedZoneId: XXXXX
    HostedZoneId: XXXX
    Name: ${self:custom.frontendBucketName}
    Type: 'A'

RedirectDnsRecord:
  Type: "AWS::Route53::RecordSet"
  Properties:
    AliasTarget:
      DNSName:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - RedirectCloudFrontDistribution
          - DomainName
      HostedZoneId: XXXX
    HostedZoneId: XXXX
    Name: ${self:custom.redirectBucketName}
    Type: 'A'
```

Comment: It isn't clear from your description just what you mean is happening here: *"If I hit example.com it does not redirect to www.example.com, only when I have clicked another link on the site."*  Can you provide the domain name? It should be simple enough to diagnose, but is not obvious based on the info known so far.  You definitely do not need a default root object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have a DNS problem, you haven't published DNS record for "www.example.com".

You have DNS for example.com --> CloudFront but not for www.example.com , even though you have added www.example.com to a CloudFront CNMAE/Alternative filed, when client gets a 301/302 with a new location and see the change in host, it resolves it again.

curl -I --resolve www.example.com:443:13.249.210.66 https://www.example.com/index.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 80232
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sun, 23 Jun 2019 10:07:43 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 21 Jun 2019 07:21:38 GMT
ETag: "8d536768b2173a7f3869f4178f75b331"
Server: AmazonS3
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 7db8064d915149cac923df11147875f9.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: BLR50-C3
X-Amz-Cf-Id: wOpVoz1gVlxYDBORSfGr9fmt8L-Q6vhWyEm1XPgJVQy-sbes9HTuuQ==

You just need to create a alias record in Route53 for www.example.com as well.

Comment: Yes, thats because you have cache behaviour set to redirect HTTP to https, you'll see two redirection, first http to https by cloudfront and then s3 redirects it to www. If you don't want two redirections, you can set the cloudfront distribution(surfquipment.com) to serve on both http and https instead of redirect in cache behaviour.

Comment: I think I understand the issue, but do not exactly know what to change in my `RedirectCloudFrontDistribution` defined above?

Comment: you need to set ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all of the distribution with CNAME-surfquipment.com.