# s3 static site + cloudfront + SSL not working for non www

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, static, amazon-cloudfront, namecheap

I have a static html site hosted on a s3 bucket. I have generated a free ssl certificate with let's encrypt which I imported into ACM.

```
certbot --manual --server https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

I have setup cloudfront to use that certificate.

On my DNS provider (namecheap) I have set a CNAME that points www to the  cloudfront domain name, and also put a redirect from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com

Now if I go to

https://www.example.com, it works

https://example.com, it hangs until it times out

Can someone tell me what I'm a missing ?

Answer (score 2):

> On my DNS provider (namecheap) I have ...  put a redirect from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com

There's the problem.  Your "DNS provider" has a redirect service that doesn't support HTTPS.  There is no way they can -- a redirect can only occur *after* an HTTPS connection is made, and an HTTPS connection requires a valid certificate.

Redirects are never actually done in DNS, though your provider's interface may give you that impression. Redirects are always done with a web server.  Your provider has a web server that they provision and point the DNS there when you configure one hostname to redirect to another.

In short, there's not really a way to do this at the domain apex without using Route 53 as your authoritative DNS host.  You don't have to transfer your domain name registration to the Route 53 registrar, but you'll need to use Route 53 for your DNS, and you'll need a second bucket and a second CloudFront distribution -- see [Supporting HTTPS URL redirection with a single CloudFront distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35616286/1695906).

Comment: Wow this is crazy! It is going to cost me more (2 cloudfront + route53) to do all this circus than paying directly namecheap to get me the the certificate. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Marco This is not due to the certificate (which you can by the way issue for free using ACM and assign to your CF distribution). What he meant in this post is that redirecting will always involve a web server (and a 301 redirection).

If you use [dig](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/) on the domain you set up the redirection for, you can see for yourself that it's not pointing to the IP address you set up in the A record, but rather to Namecheap's server which is responsible for doing the redirect. It's just a convenience (you could just do this directly on your web server)