# AWS S3site with CloudFront - https issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a problem with a website I'm hosting in S3 and distributing via CloudFront.

In S3 have created 2 buckets, one for example.com and one for www.example.com both set to static webhosting and the www.example.com forwarding to example.com

In Route 53 I have a hosted zone for both sites with A record to the Cloudfront distribution

In CloudFront I have a distribution with CNAME/Alternate Domain Names for both www.example.com and example.com and I also have origin paths for both the s3 bucket paths for both www.example.com and example.com

When I browse to https://example.com it works fine
When I browse to https://www.example.com it doesn't load and I get an error: Server IP address could not be found

What am I missing?

Comment: *I have a hosted zone for both sites* ...so you have one hosted zone, or two?

Answer (score 0):

You should make only 1 cloudfront distribution, and then redirect traffic from www.example.com to example.com (or vice versa). See [this link.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/root-domain-website-hosting-for-amazon-s3/)

Edit: got some clarification on the issue from the comment. The way I have it setup for one of my domains is the following:

S3 has redirect setup on www.example.com, redirect requests to example.com using https protocol

Cloudfront distribution (pointed at example.com bucket) has a behavior set for redirect all HTTP to HTTPS

I think if you have the redirect behaviour on cloudfront setup this way along with the S3 redirect, it should work.

Comment: this is exactly what i have done. I have created the s3 buckets with the redirect. and i have created a single cloudfront distribution (but it has CNAME and origin path for both domains). it works (the redirect) on http but not https - that is http://www.example.com redirects to https://example.com but https://www.example.com throws an error as above

Comment: Got it, edited my answer, please try it the way I have it setup and let me know if it works

Comment: [This setup requires two CloudFront distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35614734/1695906).  The solution in the AWS blog post does not support HTTPS on the domain that redirects -- only HTTP.  
 However, that doesn't explain *"server IP address could not be found,"* which sounds like a Route 53 misconfiguration.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you - so rather than have 1 distribution with 2 origin paths/cnames, i need a distribution for each?